# Do I need custom backend for django If my User model is custom?

Tags: django, customization, backend

A quick question.I had implemented a custom user model with its manager .Registration is working great ,but whenever user is logging in it shows  AnonymousUser. Does this mean that I need to implement cutsom backend ot what ?? if yes could anyone give me an example of custom backend for custom user model.
Kind regards
EDIT:here is my settings file

```
  INSTALLED_APPS = [
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'custom_user' ,
       ]

     ROOT_URLCONF = 'jam.urls'



     WSGI_APPLICATION = 'jam.wsgi.application'
    AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('custom_user.backends.ClientAuthBackend', 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')

  DATABASES = {
       'default': {
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
             'NAME':'test3',
             'USER':'root',
             'PASSWORD':'',
         }
     }

      AUTH_USER_MODEL='custom_user.EmailUser'


   LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

   TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

   USE_I18N = True

   USE_L10N = True

   USE_TZ = True


   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and this is backends.py

```
class ClientAuthBackend(object):
   def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
                try:
                    user = EmailUser.objects.get(email=username)
                    if EmailUser.check_password(password, user.password):
                            return user
            except EmailUser.DoesNotExist:
                    return None
    def get_user(self, user_id):
            try:
                    return EmailUser.objects.get(pk=user_id)
            except EmailUser.DoesNotExist:
                    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

a quick answer - no you dont need custom backend. If you want to replace the user model, [you need to set](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.YourUserModel'`

custom backend is needed if you want to change something in authentication (can also be other reasons) cycle. e.g. authenticate against email instead of username etc ...

Comment: I do have AUTH_USER_MODEL set but something is worng with authentication whenever I logged in user it shows that user is ananymous

Comment: @AlbertStepanyan then your data is probably coming from django's user model?

Comment: no it's coming from simple login form ,also I tried custom backend but even it didn't solve the problem

Comment: @AlbertStepanyan can you share more relevant code? Because what doniyor has stated is correct, you can probably share your settings file